# UITableViewCell customization

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

If I want to fully customize my UITableViewCell, should I create a subclass of UITableViewCell or just create a subclass of UIView and do this ?

`tableViewCell.backgroundView = [UICustomView alloc] init]; tableViewCell.selectedView = [UICustomView alloc] init];`

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/312/beautiful-table-view-helper-class

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer to Create a subclass of UITableViewCell.
try this [link](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/ipad-development/custom-table-view-cells-in-ipad-programming/).

Answer (score 0):

What is your customization? If it is about backgroundview of your cell, you seem to be following the right track. The answer depends on what you what you want to achieve.

Subclassing UITableViewCell isn't unusual, but you should only do it if the drawing of UITableViewCell carries much detailed logic. In usual cases, you can simply get away by changing some public properties of UITableViewCell within cellforrowatindexpath delegate method of UITableView datasource.

Comment: I want to change the frame of the imageView , textLabel and detailLabel of those tableViewCells.I also want to add new UILabel into it because by default it's not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create subclass of UITableViewCell.
refere below one:
http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/how-to-add-a-custom-uitableviewcell-to-a-xib-file-objective-c/

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new `UITableViewCellViewController`, design it and fetch the data.. It is simple than any other approach.